# Compare two arrays and populate with elements that don't exist in first array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that looks like this, i simply need to take object with id 3 from $allItems and put it in $existingItems array, i tried something like this but im unable just to take elements that don't exist in $existingItems.

```
$existingItems = array[{
      id: 1
      name: 'jon doe',
      events: [{..},{..}]
},{
      id: 2,
      name: 'jane doe',
      events: [{..},{..}]
}]

$allItems = array[{
      id: 1
      name: 'jon doe'
      events: null
},{
      id: 2,
      name: 'jane doe',
      events: null
},{
      id: 3,
      name: 'David Beckam',
      events: null
}];

foreach ($existingItems as $key => $existingValue) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($allItems as $key => $value) {
        if($existingValue['id'] === $value['id']) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
        if($found == false)
            $existingItems [] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#refsect1-function.array-diff-examples) is your friend!

Comment: Im not sure how to use it with objects, can you show me ?

Comment: Your arrays are not well formed. Where are they coming from? Can you show us how they look in PHP?

Comment: I already got correct answer, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `foreach` loops in the wrong order. Since you are looping the existing array in the outer loop, and the existing array doesn't have any id=3, it won't be able to find it. You need to put `$allItems` as the outer loop and `$existingItems` as the inner loop like this:

```
foreach ($allItems as $value) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($existingItems as $key => $existingValue) {
        if($existingValue['id'] === $value['id']) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($found == false) {
        $existingItems[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Also note that the `$found == false` check had to be moved outside the inner loop because you have to wait until you search every item in the inner loop.